# 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object. Sharepoint 2010

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010

When I debug my project it creates a sharepoint app in the sharepoint site collection where i specify all the fields necessary and in between, I get the following errors.

### 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Hide Genehmigerbox
    $("[id$='Superior_upLevelDiv']").parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().hide();
    //Füge Genehmigerbutton hinzu
    $("#SPFieldTextSuperior").append(newTable);
    //overwrite entity function
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("overwriteEntityFunction");
    //add click
    $("input[name$='phoneOwner']:eq(1)").bind("click", function () {
        $("div[title='People Picker']:eq(0)").text($cUserLoginName);
        $("a[title='Check Names']:eq(0)").click();
    });

    clickToLoad();
});
```

---

I'm thinking, it's something related with JQuery.

Any idea what the problem might be?

Thanks.

Comment: which jquery version do you use? where do you include your jquery script? a missing jquery script file would be the most obvious reason for this error.

Comment: Yes i think too. should i specify certain path or should i give the path where the jquery is downloaded or stored.

Answer (score 0):

seems you are missing a reference to the jquery library. you can either download and add your own script path or reference a web base script source, e.g.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

depending on the version you need you can find more here:
https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide?hl=de#jquery